# Writing data on HDFS taking very long time

Tags: scala

Writing file on HDFS creating many part files(200) and taking very long time

I am loading hive table(using SqlContext.sql) into Dataframe 1(6K records) and registering into temp table. I am left joining temp table with another hive table(5 Million records) and loading into dataframe 2. I am updating dataframe 1 with dataframe 2 values using left outer join and  i am trying to write dataframe_1(6K records) into HDFS file which is taking 1 hour 30 min. I have tried 
repartition(dataframe_1.rdd.repartition(2)) 
writing file without coalesce(1) 
writing just one record to see if it is faster
but did not help. Even show(10) records on dataframe_1 is taking long time.
I am writing code in Zeppelin using spark interpreter. I do not have access to any configuration settings as well.Need to contact support team for that.

I am new to big data platforms . Any hep would be greatly appreciated.

```
%spark

import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val fs=FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val Dataframe_1 = sqlContext.sql("""select * from  Hive_Table_1""")
Dataframe_1.registerTempTable("Dataframe_table")

val Dataframe_2 = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * FROM 
(select B.col1,    B.col2,    A.col4,    B.col3 FROM Dataframe_table A 
left join  Hive_Table_2  B on a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2) A """ )

val Dataframe_1 = 
Dataframe_1.join(Dataframe_2,Seq("col1","col2"),"leftouter")
.withColumn("col3", when($"col3".isNotNull,"Path Found").otherwise("Path 
Not Found"))

Dataframe_1.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header","true").save("/abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you said, you disabled writing to HDFS and the job is still slow it means that writing to HDFS is not a bottleneck. And that is expected: the size of the result is the same as the size of the first dataframe (6k records). Writing it should be pretty fast anyway.
So most probably your issue comes from join. And yes, joins of huge tables could potentially take hours.

To verify such things I usually replace `.write` with `.count` to isolate io operations. But it might not work in your case since spark sql api could potentially optimize `.count`.

Also you should replace `coalsece` with `repartition` since the former eliminates parallelism.

Comment: Without hdfs writing, job is pretty fast. It takes just 2 mins. Problem starts when i start writing  joined data onto hdfs or when i try to show joined data using show() method. Are you saying  below code  writes data fast. Dataframe_1.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header","true").save("/abc")

Comment: You can't just remove writing to disk. Spark uses lazy evaluation model. So if you don't call an action like `write` of `show` that actually triggers computation you can't measure performance. I'm not saying that `repartition` will work fast. But `coalesce` will be definitely slower. Or you could call `coalesce(1, shuffle = true)` which is equivalent to `repartition`.

Comment: Okay. I will try coalesce with shuffle and check the performance.

Comment: coalesce(1, shuffle = true)  is giving the error "too many arguments  for method coalesce"

Comment: Then it doesn't exist for Sql api. Only for Rdd. Just use repartition.